# android service foreground screen lock mode

Tags: android, delphi, service, location, foreground

I need to detect when the android smartphone goes into lock screen mode and when it comes out.

I need it to be able to bring a service respectively in start foreground and stop foreground so that the location sensor continues to work both when the smartphone is off (on lock screen) and when it is on.

Is there a fast way to do this detection without having to use the kastri library?

Prefer not to be dependent on the kastri library. That's why I asked for this.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the code from Kastri to do this? The work (and it is **not** trivial to do this) is all already done for you.

Comment: Yes, you can do that without using Kastri or any other library. First you need to start reading Android documentation and then implement everything necessary one step at the time. If you get stuck on individual step you can come and ask here if the question has not been previously asked. For now, your question is just not suitable here.